# What is Mathematica's ML Linear Regression Method?

Tags: fitting, machine-learning, implementation-details

When I run `p = Predict[trainingSet, Method -> "LinearRegression"];`, how is that different from just running ordinary least squares?

It's quite slow on a training set of 10000 examples, each with six features, so I presume something a bit more sophisticated than OLS must be going on? It's also then quite slow to apply the predictor function: `predictions = p /@ trainingSet[[;;, 1]];`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in [the documentation for `Predict[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Predict.html#322140253), it claims to do $L^2$ regularization, so its results for `Method -> "LinearRegression"` are not equivalent to what you'll get for e.g. `LinearModelFit[]`.

To get results equivalent to `LinearModelFit[]`, you need to set `"L2Regularization" -> 0`.

```
train = {1 -> 1.3, 2 -> 2.4, 3 -> 4.4, 4 -> 5.1, 6 -> 7.3};

p1 = Predict[train, Method -> {"LinearRegression", "L2Regularization" -> 0}];

p2 = LinearModelFit[List @@@ train, {1, x}, x];

{p1[5/2], p2[5/2]}
   {3.25338, 3.25338}
```

---

However, there is something off in [their description](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/method/LinearRegression.html#337800727) for [$L^2$ (Tikhonov) regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization). If it is true that Tikhonov is being done behind the scenes, then a manual reimplementation ought to give the same results:

```
λ = 1; (* regularization parameter *)

p1b = Predict[trainingset,
              Method -> {"LinearRegression", "L1Regularization" -> 0, 
                         "L2Regularization" -> λ,
                         "OptimizationMethod" -> "NormalEquation"}];

{dm, rv} = Through[{DesignMatrix[#, {1, x}, x] &, #[[All, -1]] &}[List @@@ train]];

(* minimize the loss function *)
{ar, br} = FindArgMin[#.# &[rv - dm.{a, b}] + λ {a, b}.{a, b}, {a, b}]
   {0.256849, 1.18493}

(* directly solve the modified normal equations *)
{ar, br} = LinearSolve[Transpose[dm].dm + λ IdentityMatrix[2], Transpose[dm].rv]
   {0.256849, 1.18493}
```

but

```
{p1b[5/2], ar + br 5/2}
   {3.39448, 3.21918}
```

so there is something additional/different being done behind the scenes.